# Ionic2 RC0 - How to move own libraries to build folder now that gulp is gone?

Tags: angular, ionic2

[image]

Ionic Team eliminated Gulp from their project. How am I supposed to get my libraries going now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been storing libraries in `src/assets` folder. Everything you add to `src/assets` gets copied to `www/assests`. And then I reference them in index.html as `<script src="assets/my-library.js"></script>`

Comment: Thats funny. Convention says vendors is the directory of choise for js files. assets is for images. Any idea where to change this?

Comment: Look into ionic-app-scripts: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/

Ultimately this is the file you want to override: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/copy.config.js

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not copy. I searched for `copy.config.js` in my project but did not find. I must say I upgraded and did not create new project from scratch.

Comment: copy.config.js will not be in your project because it is a dependency through npm. You may need to install the latest version of @ionic/app-scripts in your package.json devDependencies

Comment: Isn't that solution problematic? If some day, someone at the ionic team decides to change the default copy.config.js, and my project now directs to the custom one I made, won't it break the chain?

Comment: It works though... using package.json: "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --copy ./config/copy.config.js",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch --copy ./config/copy.config.js", ...

Comment: To my understanding they want you to make your own app-scripts (if you so desire). Then you are supposed to use the `config` property in `package.json` to map your own file to overwrite theirs: `config: { "ionic_copy":"./config/my-copy.js", "ionic_rollup":"./config/my-rollup.js" }`. See the docs from my first comment for the config keys to use